# Как из одного шаблона jinja передать значения другому (Django, Python)

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, django, django-filter

Есть два шаблона (home и card), через функцию views.py я передаю модель главному шаблону home. В home встроен цикл, который создает card. Как передать значения в card?

То есть я хочу передавать в home.html только модель, чтобы home.html создавало карточку и рисовала card.html. Проблема в том что я не могу из home.html задать параметры jinja для card.html

```html
{% extends 'homepage.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        {% for program in programs %}
            <div class="col">
                {% include 'card.html' %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src = '{{ image }}' class="card-img-top" alt='{{ image_text }}'>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ card_title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ card_text }}</p>
    <a href = '{{ card_btn_link }}' class="btn btn-primary">{{ card_btn_text }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `card` используются переменные (например, `{{ image }}`), которые не объявлены в `home`.
Попробуйте перед включением шаблона объявлять эти переменные. Не знаю, как у вас реализована модель `program`, но объявление переменных будет выглядеть примерно так:

```html
{% extends 'homepage.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        {% for program in programs %}
            <div class="col">
                {% with image = program.image %}
                {% with image_text = program.image_text %}
                {% with card_btn_link = program.card_btn_link %}
                {% with card_btn_text = program.card_btn_text %}

                {% include 'card.html' %}

                {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Подробнее о переменных в jinja2 можно почитать [тут](https://pythonru.com/uroki/7-osnovy-shablonizatora-jinja)

Comment: спасибо, это решило проблему. только вместо set я использовал with, т.к. в django set использовать нельзя (почему-то) '{% with card_title=program %}
            {% with image=program.image_program%}
            {% with image_text="" %}
            {% with card_text=program.description%}
            {% with card_btn_text='Просмотреть' %}
            {% with card_btn_link=program.slug%}
            <div class="col">
                {% include 'card.html' %}
            </div>
            {% endwith %}...'

Comment: @cpp Спасибо за отзыв, обновил ответ